# Is the use of SAML 2.0 increasing?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

We are considering to implement log on facility using SAML 2.0 on our portal. But is the use of SAML 2.0 increasing or should I use any alternative technology ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my organization's (Ping Identity) perspective, SAML 2.0 is still going very strong and likely won't be superseded anytime soon.  There are plenty of [SAML-based products available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services#Products_that_provide_SAML_actors) - more and more popping up every day.  Major SaaS providers like [Google](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation) and [Salesforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com) have standardized on SAML 2.0 SSO, and we've seen [over 1500 others](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/marketplace-integration-home-page) do so as well.

There's some evidence to believe that [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/) based SSO - or most likely [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) (built on top of OAuth 2) - will eventually become as predominant.  At the moment it's mostly focused on consumer facing identity providers & applications like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.

SAML still reigns supreme in the business / enterprise world, where strong trust (federation) relationships are required.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, that was very helpful! I wait to see if other is contributing their experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Our school recently jumped on board the SAML 2.0 train. All of our students have access to Gmail for their school accounts. Now we are going to be using a cloud storage service for the students as well, employing SAML again for it. We are the Identity Providers (IdP) and our clients are Service Providers (SP).

I'm specifically using simplesamlphp for SSO generation, but that's merely my flavor preference. Java seems to be the other big platform SAML is used on. Either way, I don't foresee its use in the education industry going anywhere soon.